# How to pass latitude n longitude values from LocationServices activity which extends Service to MainActivity to display them onscreen instead of Log.d

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, location

The code in LocationService *extends* Service activity is this:

```
private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
        if(locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null) {
            double latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
            double longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
            Log.d("LOCATION_UPDATE","\nLat: "+ latitude +"\nLon: "+ longitude);
        }
    }
};
```

and the code in MainActivity *extends* AppCompatActivity activity that calls the activity on button click is:

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonStartLocationUpdates).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                startLocationService();     
            }
        }
    });
```

I have 2 TexViews with id latView and lonView to display the latitude and longitude.
The idea is to display the updating latitude and longitude that we get from LocationService to be displayed when the start button is clicked.
I'm new to android and can't seem to get it correct. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is

1. move locationCallback to MainActivity, so it has the access to the TextView, you can easily write

   textView1.text = "$latitude"
2. Create parameter to startLocation service, like

   startLocationService(LocationCallback)

then you can pass the locationCallback to the service.

Not sure if location callback is called in the ui thread. If not, you will need to call

```
runOnUiThread {
  textView1.text = "$latitude"
}
```

So this will be all in MainActivity:

```
private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
        if(locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null) {
            double latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
            double longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
            textView1.setText("" + latitude);
            textView2.setText("" + longtitude);
        }
    }
};

....

startLocationService(locationCallback);
```

Comment: Um, Can you show me how to implement it? I can't seem to get it to work. Is the "runOnUiThread{ } going under MainActivity or LocationService activity?